# how to add a custom header that can encapsulate the ip header

Tags: c

I want to encapsulate the ip header of a packet in a custom header that will contain some information regarding the type of packet. I need to do this for a project. Can someone guide me on how to go about it, Basically how to encapsulate the ip header into the custom header. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is that encapsulation used for? VPN, Logging, Tunneling, ...

Comment: Basically i needed to change the frame control bytes in the mac header so that when my packet reaches the pox controller it can take a decision for the packet by looking at the mac header. but that is not possible in pox. so i thought i can encapsulate the ip header into a custom header that can give some information regarding the type of packet like its tcp or udp etc but without going into the network layer. If you have any other suggestions on how to go about this kindly do let me know. Any suggestion will do. thnx